# How to sort based on a datetime string in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime

How to sort this list

```
tab = [
{'date': '03.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'},
{'date': '04.06.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'},
{'date': '12.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'},
{'date': '12.12.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}]
```

I am using this for sorting:
`tab.sort(key=lambda r: r['date'])`
and I get this:

```
{'date': '03.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
{'date': '04.06.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
{'date': '12.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
{'date': '12.12.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
```

but I need this:

```
{'date': '03.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
{'date': '12.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
{'date': '04.06.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
{'date': '12.12.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}
```

The format of the date is: DAY.MONTH.YEAR HOUR:MINUTE

Comment: How to convert string to datetime object?

Comment: Voting to close as non reproducible because OP is using a different time format than stated in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Convert string to datetime object, then sort.

```
from datetime import datetime

print(sorted(tab, key=lambda  x : datetime.strptime(x['date'], "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")))
```

```
[{'date': '03.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'},
 {'date': '12.05.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'},
 {'date': '04.06.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'},
 {'date': '12.12.2020 08:16', 'desc': '52dfacz', 'value': '9,33'}]
```

Comment: How to convert this list to an object?

Comment: What do you mean by converting to an object ?

Comment: Convert string to datetime object - how?

Comment: The question was about sorting, not about "object conversion" - do not move the goal posts.

Comment: Ok, but I need this to sort the list

Comment: @Kris which it does

Comment: @Kris- this sorts the list - did you try it out?

Comment: I get this: ```ValueError: time data '03.05.2020, 08:16' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M' ```

Comment: @Kris, see pattern in the question & above pattern there is a mismatch there is a additional comma in there.

Comment: '03.05.2020 08:16', not '03.05.2020, 08:16' for the format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'

Comment: @Kris In the input you provided the date strings do not contain a comma. In the error you posted, there is a comma. Please try to understand how the answer works, what it does and what the error you receive means and not blindly copy-pasting and expect **everything** to work

Comment: I removed the comma(sorry), still it does not work

Comment: How to add comment in this: "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M